# How to account for population stratification in Fisher test?

Tags: fishers-exact-test, stratification

When performing a logistic regression this can be done by adding covariates. How could I do the same for a Fisher test?

Comment: Use logistic regression.

Comment: I'm trying to see if co-mutations are more frequent than one mutation alone. How would I translate this into logistic regression?